# EF Core calls INSERT instead of UPDATE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I call UPDATE, but a new line is added. Why is this possible? The ID in the model is correct. Even if I leave purely Refresh in the manager, it still happens that way.
Model:

```cs
public class Drink
{    
    public Drink()
    {
        ImagesCount = 0;
        Hidden = false;
    }
    
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key()]
    public int DrinkId { get; set; }
                  
    public string Title { get; set; }       
    
    public int Price { get; set; }               
    
    public int ImagesCount { get; set; }
    
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
}
```

Repository:

```cs
public void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    dbSet.Update(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Manager:

```cs
public void SaveDrink(Drink drink)
{
    if (drink.DrinkId != 0)
    {
         drinkRepository.Update(drink);
    } else {
         drinkRepository.Insert(drink);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the DrinkId is not equal to 0?

Comment: @DJ Burb Yes, I made the ID output when editing, it is not 0.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I forgot to add a field with ID to the View, it was not sent to POST. The GET ID was displayed.

Comment: @WebFR please post your ```SaveDrink```actions's view (cshtml)file code.

Comment: @PritomSarkar I wrote above that I already found a bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the status of the entities via ChangeTracker

```
public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
       // ste breakpoint and check your entity status here
       var status = context.ChangeTracker.Entries();
       
       dbSet.Update(entity);
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

maybe your entity is not tracked by ChangeTracker, in this case, you need to set the entity status as  Modified.

```
 DbSet.Attach(entity);
 var entry = Context.Entry(entity);
 entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I forgot to add a field with ID to the View, it was not sent to POST. The GET ID was displayed.